# Regexreplace all lowercase words not working with german umlauts

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, regex-replace

Trying this to replace all lowercase words is not working properly

```
=regexreplace(A1;"\b[a-züöäß]+\b";"")
```

Example sentence:

> Mit Sätzen wie Gewinne laufen lassen Verluste begrenzen können vor
> allem weniger erfahrene Aktienkäufer oder Börseneinsteiger die
> wichtigsten Grundregeln des Aktienhandels kennenlernen und besser
> verinnerlichen.

also matches "ätzen" in "Sätzen" but Sätzen start with uppercase. Or matches "Aktienkäufer" to "Aktienk".

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the word boundaries are not working as expected because the German umlaut characters are considered non word characters.  Try this version:

```
=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXREPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(A1, " ", "  "), "(^| )[a-züöäß]+( |$)", ""), "  ", " "))
```

Comment: Thx, but this is not working properly. This is not matching every lowercase word.

Comment: @user3392296 The regex pattern you want here is `(?<!\S))[a-züöäß]+(?!\S)`, but Google Sheets probably does not support lookarounds.  I have edited my answer which should be closer now to your goals.

Answer (score 1):

This is working

```
=INDEX(TEXTJOIN(" "; 1; LAMBDA(x;IF(REGEXMATCH(x&""; "^[a-züöäß]");;x))(SPLIT(A1; " "&CHAR(10)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your text includes german umlaut characters

You want to *"replace all lowercase words"*

We always **use this simple formula**

```
=REGEXREPLACE(G106," [a-züöäß]+","")
```

If you **also** want to **omit the first word** you can try

```
=REGEXREPLACE(G106,"^\w+ | [a-züöäß]+","")
```

It even works as an **arrayformula**

```
=INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(G106:G109,"^\w+ | [a-züöäß]+",""))
```

*(**Do** adjust the formulae according to your ranges and locale)*

[image]